# Simple Firebase Rules about validation

Tags: android, validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase database and collecting users with their GPS coordinates and last timestamp from server side. Such as

> +users
>
> - userId
>
>   - userLocation
>   - lastTimestamp

Well I want add a firebase Rules which is a user can read only who close to him (for example around the 1 km) and in time (such as people who has been there in for 30 min ). Is that possible to solve in firebase rules segment with newData and validate comments?

Comment: Use geofire to query with a specific radius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store and retrieve the locations using geofire.

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java

**Setting location data**

```
geoFire.setLocation("userId", new GeoLocation(37.7853889, -122.4056973));
```

**Geo Queries**

```
// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 0.6 kilometers
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6);
```

And to add a time limit change the read rule for your specific data.

```
// only messages from the last 30 minutes can be read
".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 18000000)",
```

Comment: geofire looks nice but I want make it simple. for example coordinates coming like this 37.76... and -122.40.... so after decimal 2 digit is very importand for example -+0.02 tolerans is would be my respond. such as 37.78.... and -122.42.... is very close to my coordinat. how can vaildate like this. can I explained? "data.child('latitude').val() > (myloc - 0.02)"  && "data.child('latitude').val() < (myloc + 0.02)" ,

Answer (score 0):

I think its in geofire where you set the radius.
I'm also new to firebase so I'm not really familiar with it.
well check this one.
https://github.com/firebase/geofire